# Material UI Switch custom class react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customise the color of the switch in [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/api/switch/) with their `classes` props. The reason I don't want to use `withStyles` HOC is because I am creating a custom Formik switch that can be re-used everywhere around my application.

However after exporting class like these [examples](https://mui-treasury.com/styles/switch/) I always get

> The key `switchBase` provided to the classes prop is not valid for ForwardRef(Switch).
>   You need to provide a non empty string instead of: [object Object].

For every object in the styles.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here's the hook that returns the custom styles object:

```
const usePurpleSwitch = () => {
  return {
    root: {
      padding: 7
    },
    thumb: {
      width: 24,
      height: 24,
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      boxShadow:
        "0 0 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.38)"
    },
    switchBase: {
      color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.38)",
      padding: 7
    },
    track: {
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: purple[300]
    },
    checked: {
      "& $thumb": {
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      },
      "& + $track": {
        opacity: "1 !important"
      }
    },
    focusVisible: {}
  };
};
```

Here's my class:

```
export const FormikSwitch = ({ name, label }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const purple = usePurpleSwitch();

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    e => {
      console.log(purple);
      setFieldValue(name, e.target.checked);
    },
    [name, setFieldValue]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          className={classes.margin}
          name={name}
          control={(
            <Switch
              checked={field.value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              classes={purple}
            />
          )}
          label={label}
        />
      </FormGroup>
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <p className="text-warning">{meta.error}</p>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

FormikSwitch.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `usePurpleSwitch()` with `makeStyles`.

[See the demo here which has working styles](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-switch-style-fix-gtx9m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) (note - I have removed the functionalities)

**Code snippet**

```js
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { FormGroup, FormControlLabel, Switch } from "@material-ui/core";
import { usePurpleSwitch } from "./usePurpleSwitch";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(usePurpleSwitch());

export const FormikSwitch = ({ name, label }) => {
  const purple = useStyles();

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        name={name}
        control={
          <Switch
            // checked={field.value}
            checked={true}
            // onChange={handleChange}
            classes={purple}
          />
        }
        label={label}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no focusVisible props in React Material UI Switch.
I try similar approaches to my projects and all worked fine.
Please try to remove focusVisible and try again.
Hope this helps you

Comment: Doesn't work, every of the object inside the hooks are `not valid for ForwardRef(Switch)`

Comment: Please try with classes = {{...purple}}

Comment: Still getting it. and the class does not render correctly with this as well. It renders as `MuiSwitch-root [object Object] purpleSwitch`. It doesn't render to a correct class this is so weird

Comment: Oh, why don't you use makeStyles? please try makeStyles({root: ...})
I thought you used it already. You should use makeStyles to convert each keywords to Mui~-keyword